# Angular.js Count Down Timer not Ticking

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am writing my own countdown timer ticker in Angular.js as a service. The value shows up in the element correctly, but it is not counting down. Not sure what I am doing wrong since I have the `$interval(function(){ }, 1000);` in the service to cause a digest() and make it tick.

```
angular.module('monitorApp')
.factory('countDown', function($interval) {
    $interval(function(){ }, 1000);
    return {
        countDownTicker: function(secondsLeft) {
            secondsLeft = Math.round(secondsLeft/1000);
            return --secondsLeft;
        }
    }
});
```

Controller:

```
$scope.countDownTicker = countDown.countDownTicker(result.broadcastStamp);
```

HTML:

```
 <span class="info-test">{{ countDownTicker }}</span>
```

UPDATE: New service...still not working:

```
angular.module('monitorApp')
.factory('countDown', function($interval) {
    $interval(function(){ }, 1000);
    return {
        countDownTicker: function(secondsLeft) {
            return $interval(function(secondsLeft){
                secondsLeft = Math.round(secondsLeft/1000);
                --secondsLeft;
                }, 1000);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: not returning the interval part from factory, in fact it isn't wrapping anything. You need that interval to make the changes

Comment: Done, still not ticking down.

Comment: create a demo in jsfiddle or plunker

Comment: The interval should trigger a digest cycle every second. I suspect the issue is that seconds is not initialized.

Comment: Is it passing by value instead of reference and so therefore not updating?

Answer (score 1):

I think you are using `$interval` in the wrong way. It returns a promise which will be notified on each iteration.

See code sample in angularJS's [doc](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/%24interval) for reference.